# Difference between "hold out the possibility" and "hold the possibility"

Tags: meaning, difference

> “We’ve seen this movie before. The top economists at the International
>   Monetary Fund — the global agency created after World War II to
>   promote stability and growth in the world economy — unveil their
>   latest forecast, which is almost always weaker than its previous
>   forecast. The economists **hold out the possibility** that world growth
>   will improve if the most important countries, including China and the
>   United States, adopt sensible policies and cooperate with one
>   another.”
>
> https://www.richmond.com/opinion/columnists/robert-j-samuelson-column-why-the-global-economy-remains-so/article_049c3851-e59a-5325-9da0-e431d291ba31.html

Why does the writer use “hold **out** the possibility” instead of “hold the possibility”?   I fail to see the difference between these two expressions according to the definition of “hold out”.

> Hold out:
>
> 1 : to present as something realizable : proffer
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holdout

Comment: Have you considered the difference in meaning between 'hold' and 'hold out'?

Comment: yes，but I can not see the difference.  Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hold out means to offer, as the dictionary says. If I hold a dollar bill, it is in my hand, I possess it. It's in my hand. That's all. If I hold out a dollar bill to someone, e.g. by extending my arm, I am offering it to that person. To hold out a possibility is to offer it as a possible opportunity for consideration or action. To 'hold a possibility' does not make sense in that context.